Why does transforming our independent variable improve forecasting?
When doing OLS regression, I've heard that transforming an explanatory (or dependent)* variables can (sometimes) improve the forecasting ability of the model. Theoretically, why does this work?
I've been taught that the assumptions of OLS are only important for greater analysis of our results (t-stats, confidence intervals, p-values, standard errors). When predicting, violating the assumption of normality should not affect the predictability of the model. So I don't think its that.
Anyone have any other ideas?
Edit: *Transforming independent variables and/or dependent variables

if the true model is y=ln x then taking logs of x will forecast better?!

Huh? Saying the true model sounds like saying "cause God"

you understand linear regression can only fit a straight line?


OLS does not come with a normality assumption baked in.
Least squares estimation may be derived from a Gaussian log likelihood, but it can also stand on its own and still be shown to estimate the conditional mean.

you are asking about why to do feature engineering instead of leaving the work to a (universal function approximator) model. The answer is: transforming the features may make a simple model pick up the pattern. Then working with the simpler model is easier: If you think about e.g. polynomial models (universal function approximators) then learning the relationship y=a log(x) is hard, you will need a complete Taylor expansion and this may only converge within a certain convergence radius. However learning the relationship y=a x1 is easy, and x1 turns out to be your transformed feature x1=log(x)



But why does least squares estimation pick up the patterns easier if they're simpler. Like why does $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ work better if the patterns are simpler, shouldn't it work the same if the patters are noisier?

Maybe someone else give a better explanation but: if you think about e.g. polynomial models (universal function approximators) then learning the relationship y=alog(x) is hard, you will need a complete Taylor expansion and this may only converge within a certain convergence radius. However learning the relationship y=ax1 is easy, and x1 turns out to be your transformed feature x1=log(x)

@MichaelJones What do you mean by a “noisier” pattern?

I phrased that comment badly by using 'noisier', apologies. I more mean, what exactly in OLS makes transforming that data improve predictability. Ggjj1 comment makes sense, so thank you! If anyone wants to add I would appreciate it.
